# Connection Failure after a long idle time with SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, vb6, sql-server-2016

I have an old VB6 application that establishes a connection to the SQL Server and uses it throughout the lifetime of the application.

We recently upgraded the back end to SQL Server 2016 (from 2005) and noticed an odd issue.  If the user leaves the application idle for several hours, and then tries to do anything having to do with the database, they get run-time error `-2147219450 (80040806)` or `Connection Failure`.  The application does check the ADODB.Connection.State and it always reports that the connection is open.  We are seeing this error pretty consistently on multiple, pretty diverse (in terms of OS versions) workstations.

I haven't seen anything on Google relating to this.  Can someone shed some light on this issue?

Comment: Can you include the connection string?

Comment: @MisterPositive The connection string is pretty standard: "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=myuser;Password=mypwd;Initial Catalog=mediastar;Data Source=TST-VROSQL1SAT"

Comment: You have have to change providers.   I am in the car at the moment.  Sqlclientini or something like that.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @MisterPositive This is a VB6 application.  The link talks about .NET applications.

Comment: I know, but look at the change in provider.

Comment: @MisterPositive Not sure which one I could use for this...

Comment: @MisterPositive oh, i see.. Will try the sqlncli and see how that goes

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this issue with this driver only when connecting to sqlserver instance on my local machine. Seemed like there was a bug in the shared memory client protocol. Switching to TCP for local connections (Turning off shared mem and named pipes) solved the problem.
[image]

the error i was getting was

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server "Connection failure" SQL State: 08S01
```